# Regex PHP preg_match() parameter 2 should be a string error

Tags: php, regex

```
$lines = file('datatest.txt');
$lines = preg_grep("/word/", $lines); //founds me "word"
//$lines = preg_replace("/\(([^\d]+)\)/", '',  $lines2); //removing brackets with text
preg_match('/"(.*?)"/', $lines, $result); //after this line I am getting an error
```

Input from file:

```
Random (aaa) "word"
```

Output should be looking like this:

```
word
```

As I know I have an array from file with string, but why on earth I am getting this error?

Comment: Any possible ways to convert array to string?

Comment: Use `implode()`. Or run regex on each element in a loop. It all depends on what you need to obtain.

Comment: Are you just trying to get `"word"` from each line of the file? Better you clarify your requirements

Answer (score 2):

On line `preg_match('/"(.*?)"/', $lines, $result);`

$lines is not a string:
`preg_grep()` Returns the `array` consisting of the elements of the input array that match the given pattern.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php

And `preg_match()` only accepts a `string` as 2nd argument.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

**Solution**

If you know for sure $lines contains the lines of the file, you can pass them 1 by one in a for(each) loop.